# fastest way to compare string elements with each other

Tags: c#, string, performance, string-comparison

I have a list with a lot of strings (>5000) where I have to take the first element and compare it to all following elements. Eg. consider this list of string:
`{ one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten }`. Now I take `one` and compare it with `two, three, four, ...` afterwards I take `two` and compare it with `three, four, ...`

I believe the lookup is the problem why this takes so long. On a normal hdd (7200rpm) it takes about 30 seconds, on a ssd 10 seconds. I just don't know how I can speed this up even more. All strings inside the list are ordered by ascending and it is important to check them in this order. If it can speed things up considerably I would not mind to have an unordered list.

I took a look into hashset but I need the checking order so that would not work even with the fast contain method.

EDIT: As it looks like I am not clear enough and as wanted by Dusan here is the complete code. My problem case: I have a lot of directories, with similar names and am getting a collection with all directory names only and comparing them with each other for similarity and writing that. Hence the comparison between hdd and ssd. But that is weird because I am not writing instantly, instead putting it in a field and writing in the end. Still there is a difference in speed. 
Why did I not include the whole code? Because I believe my core issue here is the lookup of value from the list and the comparison between the 2 strings. Everything else should already be sufficiently fast, adding to list, looking in the blacklist (hashset) and getting a list of dir names.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Similarity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Credit http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
    /// Contains approximate string matching
    /// </summary>
    internal static class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            int n = s.Length;
            int m = t.Length;
            int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        #region Properties

        private static HashSet<string> _blackList = new HashSet<string>();

        public static HashSet<string> blackList
        {
            get
            {
                return _blackList;
            }
        }

        public static void AddBlackListEntry(string line)
        {
            blackList.Add(line);
        }

        private static List<string> _similar = new List<string>();

        public static List<string> similar
        {
            get
            {
                return _similar;
            }
        }

        public static void AddSimilarEntry(string s)
        {
            similar.Add(s);
        }

        #endregion Properties

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Clean();
            var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                                .Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name).OrderBy(y => new DirectoryInfo(y).Name).ToList();

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"result.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var item in directories)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    sw.WriteLine(item);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Amount of directories: " + directories.Count());
            }

            if (directories.Count != 0)
            {
                StartSimilarityCheck(directories);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No directories");
            }

            WriteResult(similar);

            Console.WriteLine("Finish. Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void StartSimilarityCheck(List<string> whiteList)
        {
            int counter = 0; // how many did we check yet?
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (var dirName in whiteList)
            {
                bool insertDirName = true;
                if (!IsBlackList(dirName))
                {
                    // start the next element
                    for (int i = counter + 1; i <= whiteList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // end of index reached
                        if (i == whiteList.Count)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        int similiariy = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(dirName, whiteList[i]);

                        // low score means high similarity
                        if (similiariy < 2)
                        {
                            if (insertDirName)
                            {
                                //Writer(dirName);
                                AddSimilarEntry(dirName);
                                insertDirName = false;
                            }
                            //Writer(whiteList[i]);
                            AddSimilarEntry(dirName);
                            AddBlackListEntry(whiteList[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(counter);
                //Console.WriteLine("Skip: {0}", dirName);
                counter++;
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
        }

        private static void WriteResult(List<string> list)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"similar.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8, 65536))
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Clean()
        {
            // yeah hardcoded file names incoming. Better than global variables??
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"similar.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"similar.txt");
                }

                if (File.Exists(@"result.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"result.txt");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void Writer(string s)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"similar.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8, 65536))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }

        private static bool IsBlackList(string name)
        {
            return blackList.Contains(name);
        }
}
```

To fix the bottleneck which is the second for-loop insert an if-condition which checks if similiariy is >= than what we want, if that is the case then break the loop. now it runs in 1 second. thanks everyone

Comment: If you've got the memory space and don't have duplicates you may consider using a `HashSet`, it's got o(1) for search and same for delete

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You never increment `counter`, so your code doesn't do what you say it does..

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the code that is complete and actually compiles.
Also, show us the `MyOwnComparerClass.Compare` code.

Comment: Do you need to Compare the strings for equality? And if so, what to do with that?

Comment: If the strings are ordered ascending, then strings that are the same should be next to each other. You can do a linear search.

Comment: This question is not clear at all. What do you mean by "compare"? In what way do you want to use the result of the comparison? If the "strings inside the list are ordered by ascending" already, then haven't they already been compared? In what way is that comparison not useful to you? And how is the disk relevant? If the running time of your program depends on the disk, then it seems likely your current implementation is already fast enough; you are waiting on the disk, not your code. Please improve the question, so that a useful answer could be provided.

Comment: @jdphenix I can't as I wrote. I do not need to look if a value is contained inside the hashset..
ZoharPeled Comparison of string similarity using levenshtein algortihm.
Blorgbeard Ops, forgot it when pasted the code. will add it
HenkHolterman I tested the program on a hdd and on a ssd and it was faster on the ssd. dont ask me why. I dont know, I just know what Stopwatch tells me.
PetervanderHeijden I am not comparing for equal string. I compare them for similarity.
HenkHolterman immediate neighbour makes no sense because i dont know how many string are similar in the neighbourhood

Comment: _Because I believe my core issue here is the lookup of value from the list_ - your believe is wrong. This program is completely bound to the I/O. Iterating `directories` twice is the biggest mistake. Not much else to be done.

Comment: FYI and OT, `catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }` does exactly nothing. If you aren't handling an exception, just don't catch it.

Comment: @Blorgbeard argh forgot that one. thanks for pointing out.
HenkHolterman thanks your "neighbout" suggestions gave me an idea and I could fix the bottleneck.

Comment: Then please post a self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of downvotes is crazy but oh well... I found the reason for my performance issue / bottleneck thanks to the comments.

The second for loop inside `StartSimilarityCheck()` iterates over all entries, which in itself is no problem but when viewed under performance issues and efficient, is bad. The solution is to only check strings which are in the neighborhood but how do we know if they are?

First, we get a list which is ordered by ascension. That gives us a rough overview of similar strings. Now we define a `threshold` of Levenshtein score (smaller score is higher similarity between two strings). If the score is higher than the threshold it means they are not too similar, thus we can break out of the inner loop. That saves time and the program can finish really fast. Notice that that way is not bullet proof, IMHO because if the first string is `0Directory` it will be at the beginning part of the list but a string like `zDirectory` will be further down and could be missed. Correct me if I am wrong..

```
    private static void StartSimilarityCheck(List<string> whiteList)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int j = 0; j < whiteList.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            string dirName = whiteList[j];
            bool insertDirName = true;
            int threshold = 2;
            if (!IsBlackList(dirName))
            {
                // start the next element
                for (int i = j + 1; i < whiteList.Count; i++)
                {
                    // end of index reached
                    if (i == whiteList.Count)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    int similiarity = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(dirName, whiteList[i]);
                    if (similiarity >= threshold)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    // low score means high similarity
                    if (similiarity <= threshold)
                    {
                        if (insertDirName)
                        {
                            AddSimilarEntry(dirName);
                            AddSimilarEntry(whiteList[i]);
                            AddBlackListEntry(whiteList[i]);
                            insertDirName = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AddBlackListEntry(whiteList[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Ms: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Similar entries: " + similar.Count);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop uses a strange double check. This may prevent an important JIT optimization, removal of redundant range checks.

```
//foreach (var item myList)
for (int j = 0; j < myList.Count-1; j++)
{
    string item1 = myList[j];

    for (int i = j + 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
    {
       string item2 = myList[i];
       // if (i == myList.Count)
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to whatever question it is the OP's actually trying to ask. It appears to be something more appropriately offered as a comment.

Comment: The title is asking "the fastest way", which I doubt your proposed change achieves. Given that the running time depends on the disk speed, a change to help the JIT compiler isn't likely to be noticeable, never mind address the question per se. And not being able to format a comment the way you want doesn't change whether the information should be a comment or not. In some cases, chat might be a more appropriate way to express the comment, in other cases one just needs to accept that the comment won't look as nice as you'd like or is harder to express. A comment is still a comment.